# Import settings / shortcuts from an old version to the latest version installed

Tags: shortcut, customization

Today I installed 2.93 vers. and I lost all my presets, shortcuts, paid add-ons etc.
How can I import all the previous settings from the older version to the latest I just installed?

Comment: Hello, what version did you use last ?

Comment: I changed from 2.91 to 2.93

Comment: Normally when you first open blender in a new version, a popup opens and asks you wether you want to load previous settings. Try renaming the 2.93 folder in C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender, and launching Blender again. This will force the display of this popup. You can delete the old 2.93 folder afterwards. If all else fails, rename the 2.91 folder to 2.93. I would not advise to do so because it might render blender randomly unstable.

Comment: I did not do exactly that. First I went to the following folder: C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91
then i  copied the 2 subfolders config and scripts to the 2.93 folder.
Restarted Blender and all was fine. Actually when I tried to launch the program again and the Splascreen showed up, there was no writings like "copy settings from previous" or so...
It works now. Thanks. I also tried attach a screenshot of the Splashscreen, but it seems to be impossible here.