# How do I install settings from one version of Blender to another

Tags: customization, installation, settings

I've installed 3.3 and opened it a number of times. I also added a plugin. This means that the 'Install settings from a previous version' option is now missing from the splash screen. I can't find an option to import settings in the preferences menu either.

I could just copy and drop the userpref.blend file from 3.0 to 3.3 but that doesn't seem wise, as there could be changes that might cause problems.

What should I do?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228405/import-settings-shortcuts-from-an-old-version-to-the-latest-version-installed

Comment: Thanks but none of that is of use to me. I forgot to say that I'm using a Mac.

Comment: Always helps if you give all the details... I'm using Windows, but the folder details should be [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html#blender-s-directory-layout). Anyhow I see that you're now sorted.

Answer (score 1):

After searching every menu, it seems that there is no option for importing preference settings after it expires from the splash screen.

Instead I had to delete the userpref.blend file from my Mac.

This can be found by selecting GO from the finder and holding down the 'option' key so that 'Library' appears.

Under 'Library' goto 'Blender' (version) 'config' folder and delete the userpref.blend file.

Then restart Blender. This resets the splash screen so 'import settings from previous version' can now be selected.